# setText into a loop is not working as setVisibility also not

Tags: android

.setText is not working inside for loop.
And setVisibility just works after the end of  setAlphabet() 
sorry for my english...

```
private ImageButton playTeste1;
private TextView alfabeto;

public void setListeners(){
    playTeste1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playTeste1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            alfabeto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setAlphabet();
        }
    });



 public void setAlphabet(){
       try{
           String temp;
           for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
            System.out.println(alphabet);
            temp = String.valueOf(alphabet);
            alfabeto.setText(temp);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
               System.out.println("error in Thread");
           }
    }
```

Comment: Have you initialized the `TextView` and the `ImageButton` in your code using the id of the respective elements from the xml layout file?

Comment: does it throw an error ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks, yes I initialized them...

Comment: Hello, Omar, any errors...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are not on the UI Thread. In that case, you should try setting text in the runOnUIThread method.

```
public void setAlphabet(){
   try{
       String temp;
       for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++) {
        System.out.println(alphabet);
        temp = String.valueOf(alphabet);
        try {
                 // code runs in a thread
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            alfabeto.setText(temp);
                        }
                 });
           } catch (final Exception ex) {
               Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
           }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println("error in Thread");
       }
}
```

The runOnUIThread method must be called in an Activity class or on an Activity object (or subclass of it).

Comment: Please, could you help me? I need an example, I tried using UI and Async, but without success...